# How to set the number of reducers at runtime depending on the number of processing nodes in a cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is there a way to set this info at runtime depending on the total number of processing nodes?

```
job.setNumReduceTasks( NO_OF_REDUCERS );
```

So, lets say if I compile my code on a personal laptop which has just node configured, then it should set number of reducers to 1. But, if I compile it for a real large cluster, then it should set accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Check into [`org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.ClusterMetrics`](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.23.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/ClusterMetrics.html); that should contain functions to get the information you're looking for. I have it in my notes for something else; but that should provide the cluster information you are looking for as well as some other details.

I was looking into it for the number of reducers and am planning to use the `getReduceSlotCapacity` function to know how many reducers the job can consume.

hth

Comment: But, it belongs to mapred which is already deprecated in 0.20.203. I did check the same in mapreduce but no luck. So, can you please suggest an alternative?

Comment: @PiyushKansal: Thank you. I grabbed the initial info from my notes; not the updated.

Comment: ClusterStatus is what you are looking for in the new API.

Answer (score 1):

The number of reduces actually created depend on the input to the job and the cluster capacity. So in a way, you dont have to worry about that. Just dont hard code that num_reducers value. It will pick accordingly at runtime.

Also you can pass the value via command line (ie. -D mapred.reduce.tasks) to control the reduces spawned at runtime.

Comment: Thanks TejasP. You are correct to an extent. But I am using Partitioner in my implementation and thus it is very important for me to ensure that the number of reducers are at least equal to the total number of possible partitions. 

And thats explains the motivation behind this question.

Comment: That's incorrect... Hadoop defaults to a single (IdentityReducer) reducer if you don't specify. If you set it to a # higher than the cluster capacity, it will "throttle", but it doesn't just arbitrarily choose the proper # of reducers based on your job (as it does with the mappers).